# T-SQL - Insert new row into table from a select of a group of four rows

Tags: t-sql, iteration, sql-insert

I am logging the filters that users select on my web application and need to create a new row which shows what group of filters they have selected.

Due to way in which the filters are logged in the table they come in groups of four which can be seen in screenshot below:

[image]

Based on these groups of four I need to Insert a new row that contains a comma separated string into the Message field of the value(s) after the : symbol.

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is no identifier that would group the four rows together (can't see full timestamp in your sample). here is an example with a grouping column that's computed based on mod 4 and recursive cte

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (id int identity(1,1), msg varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @tab
VALUES
 ('selected: a')
,('selected: b')
,('selected: c')
,('selected: d')
,('selected: e')
,('selected: f')
,('selected: g')
,('selected: h')
,('selected: i')
,('selected: j')
,('selected: k')
,('selected: l')

;with src --add grouping column
as
(
SELECT 
    id
    ,msg = left(msg, charindex(':', msg, 1)-1)
    ,val = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(msg, CHARINDEX(':', msg, 1)+1, len(msg) ))
    ,nid = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id % 4 order by id)  
FROM @tab
)
,source --add column for recursion
as
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nid ORDER BY id)
    FROM src
)
,rcdef -- define recursive cte
AS (
    SELECT 
        nid
        ,msg
        ,val = convert(varchar(max), val)
        ,rn = 1 
    FROM source 
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        rcdef.nid
        , rcdef.msg
        ,val = convert(varchar(max), rcdef.val +',' + source.val) --concatenate vals
        ,rn = rcdef.rn + 1
    FROM rcdef
        INNER JOIN source on source.nid = rcdef.nid  and source.rn = rcdef.rn + 1
)
SELECT 
    nid, 
    val = msg + ': ' + max(val)
FROM rcdef
GROUP BY nid, msg
```